# Metaregression - Unexpected high I-squared_res with fair adjusted R-sqare

Tags: stata, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I was performing a metaregression in STATA, on about 45 studies. Please note that the original meta-analysis has a very high heterogeneity (I-squared: 100%)
When I fit my model with covariates, I manage to reach a fair R-square (36,5%), but the residual I-square (which I expected to be 100-36.5%, i.e. 63.5%), is stuck at 99.84%.
Where i did wrong? It is possible to have a so high I-squared with a fair R-square?

Comment: You might be interested in this answer on another site https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-meta-analysis/2020-September/002365.html It is about R but the general principles apply here too I think.

Comment: Ok so it seems that a large residual I-square may be compatible with a moderate R-square. 
The point is: can I report only the R-square, or do I need to report also the residual I-square? If so, how can I justify this awkward results?